# Как правильно вставить переменную в запрос?

Tags: golang

Здравствуйте, с го знаком не долго, поэтому вопрос немного "Ламерский".
Есть запрос Mysql

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='login"';)
```

Login я получил раньше и он в в формате string.
Подскажите как вставить сюда переменную?

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='Моя переменная"';)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Открываем [документацию](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query) и видим:

```
age := 27 //                                            v   vvv
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE age=?", age)
```

Обычные "порядковые параметры на заглушках": вместо значений ставятся `?`-заглушки, а последующие аргументы по порядку эти заглушки заполняют.

Пример чуточку сложнее:

```
age := 27
name := "Кнопкатык"
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE age=? AND name=?", age, name)
```